# is it ok to use the walls of the sukka as a hanger

Tags: halacha, clothing, sukkot, sukkah

Is it ok to have a nail in (sticking out of) the wall of the sukka from before sukkot and use it to hang a jacket during sukkot?

Will it make a difference if the nail is facing in or out?

A possible problem with this is found in [Shulchan Aruch O"H 638.1](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%AA%D7%A8%D7%9C%D7%97):

> The wood of the sukkah is forbidden during the entire eight days of the festival. This applies both to the wood of the walls and to the wood of the roofing.

Comment: See the Aruch HaShulchan (which has too much info for me to create a quick answer.) http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_01582.html#HtmpReportNum0547_L2

Comment: @DannySchoemann that's a very large (in bytes) page. For future reference, [Wikisource](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%94%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F) has much of _Aroch Hashulchan_, one _siman_ per page.

Answer (score 3):

It would seem from the last Remo in [סימן תרלח - סכה ונויה אסורין כל שבעה](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_01975_part_36.html#HtmpReportNum0013_L2) that it's not a problem.

Preferably you should make a condition - verbally, before that Chag begins - that the hanger is not part of the Sukka. But even if you didn't it's OK to use it.

> אֲבָל בְּנוֹיִין שֶׁנּוֹתְנִים בַּדְּפָנוֹת, כְּגוֹן סְדִינִים הַמְצֻיָּרִים, נוֹהֲגִין לְטַלְטְלָם מִפְּנֵי הַגְּשָׁמִים אֲפִלּוּ בְּלֹא תְּנַאי, מִשּׁוּם דְּיֵשׁ אוֹמְרִים דְּאֵין אִסּוּר אֲפִלּוּ בַּדְּפָנוֹת עַצְמָן, כָּל שֶׁכֵּן בְּנוֹיָן. וּמִכָּל מָקוֹם טוֹב  לְהַתְנוֹת עֲלֵיהֶם (ד''מ).‏

Answer (score 3):

Rav Eliyashiv held that it is permissible since its *k'ein taduru* (like what people do in their own home). So it isn't a disgrace to the sukkah. From Vayishma Moshe chelek 5.